# where put variable to this javascript

Tags: javascript, php

sorry for stupid question, but my head is not working anymore today and I have to finish this soon.

I have button to call AJAX:

```
<button onclick="showUser(this.value)" value="' . $row2["xxx"] . '">' . $row2["xxx"] . '</button>`
```

and function:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("maintext").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","maintext.php?q=" +str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

so far so good.
if I want to use this function with variable from php, how? Or I could write new function with the same purpose, but where to put variable? I tried:

```
if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
  echo '<script> function showUser(' . $_GET["info"] . ') </script>';
}
```

...but it doesn`t work.

Thanks for help

Comment: dont define the function again just call the funciton  echo '<script> showUser(' . $_GET["info"] . ') </script>';

Comment: Thanks, re-defining was my mistake. But stil, after redirecting on this page, function is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-defining the function. You just have to call it after (!) you defined it.

Replace

```
if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
  echo '<script> function showUser(' . $_GET["info"] . ') </script>';
}
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET['info'])) {
  echo '<script> showUser("' . $_GET["info"] . '") </script>';
}
```

Additionally you have to insert quotes (`" "`) or Javascript won't take the input as a string.

Comment: Thanks @modsfabio, re-defining was my mistake. But stil, after redirecting on this page, function is not called.

Comment: Make sure you call it after defining! Do you see any errors in console?